# Artifactory java.security.KeyStoreException - Cannot store non-PrivateKeys

Tags: ssl-certificate, artifactory, tomcat8

I am attempting to run Artifactory 7.12.6 under SSL on Windows Server 2016.

```
configVersion: 1
artifactory:
    tomcat:
        httpsConnector:
            certificateFile: E:\Wildcard.cer
            certificateKeyFile: E:\Wildcard.key
            enabled: true
            port: 8443
```

The Wildcard.key is in RSA format, e.g. `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

The error I am seeing:

```
01-Feb-2021 15:30:11.798 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
01-Feb-2021 15:30:11.954 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1077)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:100)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:72)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:246)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:587)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1075)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Cannot store non-PrivateKeys
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineSetKeyEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineSetKeyEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:111)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.setKeyEntry(KeyStore.java:1174)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:322)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:245)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:98)
        ... 20 more
```

I'm sure it's something simple I am missing. I also tried converting the RSA key to pkcs8 which failed.

Comment: I have this issue as well. Did you ever figure it out?